TCP socket programming, uploading and downloading jpg files in C
I have a problem that if I play this program, the connection between client and server has been successful. But after that, when we try the client to upload or download jpg file from server, there is some problem. I guess there is some while statement going forever.
client.c
int upload(int sock, const char* file_name){
    FILE *file_fd;
    char buff[1024];
    int bytesread, bytessent = 0;
  
    send(sock, "UPLOAD", strlen("UPLOAD"), 0);
    send(sock, file_name, strlen(file_name), 0);

    file_fd = fopen(file_name, "rb");
    
    while(bytesread = fread(buff, 1, sizeof(buff), file_fd) > 0)
    {
         bytessent = send(sock, buff, bytesread, 0);
    }
    fclose(file_fd);
    remove(file_name);
    return True;
}


int download(int sock, const char* file_name){
  
    FILE *file_fd;
    char buff[1024];
    int bytesgot = 0;

    send(sock, "DOWNLOAD", strlen("DOWNLOAD"), 8);
    send(sock, file_name, strlen(file_name), 0);

    file_fd = fopen(file_name, "wb");

    while(bytesgot = recv(sock, buff, sizeof(buff), 0) > 0)
    {
        fwrite(buff, 1, bytesgot, file_fd);
    }

    fclose(file_fd);
    return True;
}

server.c
while(True){
    n = recv(clnt_sock, buffer1, sizeof(buffer1), 0);
    buffer1[n] = '\0'; 
    // upload
    if(strncmp(buffer1, "UPLOAD", 6) == 0)
        {
            n = recv(clnt_sock, filename, sizeof(filename), 0);
            
            file_fd = fopen(filename, "wb");
            filename[n] = '\0';

            while((bytesread = recv(clnt_sock, buffer2, sizeof(buffer2), 0)) > 0) //problem
            {
                fwrite(buffer2, 1, bytesread, file_fd);
            }
            
            
            fclose(file_fd);
        }

    // download
    else if(strncmp(buffer1, "DOWNLOAD", 8) == 0)
        {
            n = recv(clnt_sock, filename, sizeof(filename), 0);
            
            filename[n] = '\0';

            file_fd = fopen(filename, "rb");

            while((bytesread = fread(buffer2, 1, sizeof(buffer2), file_fd)) > 0)
            {
                send(clnt_sock, buffer2, bytesread, 0);
            }
            fclose(file_fd);
            remove(filename);
        }

I tried many different codes, but it has not been solved.

You have a major flaw: TCP is streaming, without message boundaries. Your protocol sends the filename without any information about its length, which means the server might read part of the file-data as the name. Or not read all of the name, and the rest of the name the server will write to the file. It's the same with the "UPLOAD" command, it might get mixed with the filename.

Another major flaw is that you have almost no error checking. What happens if recv(clnt_sock, buffer1, sizeof(buffer1), 0); fails in the server?

In addition to the other problems you assume that send sends the full buffer, while it might only send a part (that's why there is a return value you SHOULD check). Also, statements like "I tried many different codes, but it has not been solved." are useless since they only state that you've tried something else but not what and what the results where.

In addition, in client.c download() you pass 8 in first send() flags. In glibc it is MSG_EOR and it makes no sense for TCP.

I was wrong about MSG_EOR numeric value. In glibc it is 0x80. 8 is MSG_CTRUNC and moreover it is not applicable for send().
